# Bootstrap 4, want four item in slider

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, responsive-slides

i want four item in one slide but in my case it shows only one

here is my code and screenshot

but in mobile view its work perfectly

my Bootstrap and JavaScript link given in code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**css**

```
div.pic{
  background-color: #353535;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  color: white;
}
```

**Code**

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 3%;">
  <div id="carouselExample" style="background-color: lightgray" class="carousel slide pointer-event" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
    <div class="carousel-inner row w-100" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 active" align="center">
        <div class="pic">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" align="center">
        <div class="pic">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" align="center">
        <div class="pic">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" align="center">
        <div class="pic">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev text-faded" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by putting 4 items in a single `div` like this:

```
<div class="carousel-item col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 active" align="center">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="pic">1</div></td>
            <td><div class="pic">2</div></td>
            <td><div class="pic">3</div></td>
            <td><div class="pic">4</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

More information:

What you basically did was to create 4 slides as usual. By adding all 4 items into the main slide it will show them all at once. Of course, it needs more refining to look good though.

Final Edit

By putting the div's in a table it forces the items into a horizontal position.

Comment: it shows all 4 item in vertical basically i need 8 item but stack overflow  policy i can't add more code in question that why i add four item in question

Comment: it should be possible to get them horizontal with some smart CSS. possibly using a css grid layout

Comment: after some more playing around with it, putting the item div's in a table forces them horizontal. check the edit again